# Modify JavaMail Code to Download Most Recent 10 Messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the following code to download messages from Gmail.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.FetchProfile;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class MailReader {

    WebDriver driver;
    Folder inbox;
    String m;

    String gmailID = "xyz@gmail.com";
    String gmailPass = "xyz";
    String storeMessage;

    public MailReader()
    {

    }

    public String readMail() {
        System.out.println("Inside readMail()...");
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

        /* Set the mail properties */

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        // Set manual Properties
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
        props.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.gmail.com");

        try

        {

            /* Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(
                    System.getProperties(), null);

            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");

            store.connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, gmailID,
                    gmailPass);

            /* Mention the folder name which you want to read. */

            // inbox = store.getDefaultFolder();
            // inbox = inbox.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

            /* Open the inbox using store. */

            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            /* Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox */

            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(
                    Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
            System.out.println("No. of Unread Messages : " + messages.length);

            /* Use a suitable FetchProfile */
            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);

            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);

            inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

            try

            {

                m = printAllMessages(messages);

                inbox.close(true);
                store.close();


            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception while connecting to server: "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
        return m;

    }

    public String printAllMessages(Message[] msgs) throws Exception
    {
        String s = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
        {

            //System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");

            s = printEnvelope(msgs[i]);
        }
        return s;

    }

    public String printEnvelope(Message message) throws Exception

    {

        Address[] a;


        // FROM

        if ((a = message.getFrom()) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
            }

        }
        // TO
        if ((a = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
            }
        }
        String subject = message.getSubject();

        Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
        Date sentDate = message.getSentDate(); // receivedDate is returning
                                                // null. So used getSentDate()

        String content = message.getContent().toString();
        System.out.println("Subject : " + subject);
        if (receivedDate != null) {
            System.out.println("Received Date : " + receivedDate.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Sent Date : " + sentDate.toString());
        System.out.println("Content : " + content);

        return(getContent(message));

    }





    public String getContent(Message msg)

    {
        try {
            String contentType = msg.getContentType();
            System.out.println("Content Type : " + contentType);
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();

            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);

            int count = mp.getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if(i == 1) {
                    return s;
                }
                //dumpPart(mp.getBodyPar((i));
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return m;
    }

/*
    public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
        // Dump input stream ..
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
        // around it.
        if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        }
        int c;
        System.out.println("Message : ");
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.write(c);


        }
    }*/

     boolean textIsHtml = false;

    /**
     * Return the primary text content of the message.
     */
    public String getText(Part p) throws
                MessagingException, IOException {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            String s = (String)p.getContent();
            textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
            return s;
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null)
                        text = getText(bp);
                    continue;
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                        return s;
                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if (s != null)
                    return s;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

I want to modify the code so that:

1. It only downloads the most recent 10 unread messages
2. It only downloads messages which are sent from a specific address (For example, only messages sent from myemail@example.com

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: On 2. you can use search terms: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Email/Searchthegivenfolderformessagesmatchingthegivencriteria.htm

Answer (score 1):

The 10 most recent messages are the last 10 messages in your INBOX.

But some of them could be read, and some of them could be deleted.  To find the 10 most recent unread messages you'll need to use a [FlagTerm](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/FlagTerm.html) to search for messages where the SEEN flag is false.  You might want to use an [AndTerm](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/search/AndTerm.html) to find messages where the DELETED flag is also false.

Note that [Folder.search](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) doesn't **download** any of the messages, it just tells you which messages match.  You can then look at the last 10 of those messages and do whatever you need to do to "download" them.

Hopefully that's enough of a hint to get you started.  If you still can't get it to work, show us what code you're using and what results you're getting.